# Resources for using Guice with Apache CXF

Tags: cxf, guice

Are there any resources for using Apache CXF with Google Guice? I know that since version 2.4.0 CXF has been unbundled from Spring and doesn't require it anymore, but I can't seem to find any real world examples/tutorials where Guice has been successfully integrated with CXF. Any such resources would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263194/cxf-and-google-guice-using-jax-rs-jax-ws/8228288

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out: http://code.google.com/p/guice-cxf/ you can get both Guice and CXF injections to work

[/shamless self-promotion]