# Publishing JAX-WS Webservice, Jetty Guice

Tags: java, soap, jetty, guice

I am trying to add SOAP service to the existing application which is using Guice and Jetty. I found similar threads on the stackoverflow, and used the method described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901617/publishing-jax-ws-webservice-with-guice-in-a-servlet-application). But afterwards when I am trying to run the application I am getting the following exception. 
Any ideas what might be causing it?

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: At least one resource class should be specified
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.getServiceClasses(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.init(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:119)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.init(ServletDefinition.java:117)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.init(ManagedServletPipeline.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:102)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at ee.ir.register.ServerModule.startServer(ServerModule.java:105)
    at ee.ir.register.App.main(App.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```